# Cannot access private property getset::$name

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to learn the magic methods __GET and __SET.  Right now I'm working on the __GET method.

And I'm getting the Cannot Access Private Property error.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

  class getset {

    private $name;

    public function __set($property, $value) {
      if((property_exists($this, $property))) {
        $this->$property = $value;
        echo "Successfully updated {$property} to {$value}";
      } else {
         echo "This failed.";
      }
    }

  }

  getset::$name = 'Thomas';

?>
```

I'm not sure what's going on.  I've looked at the parameters in a __SET function, and I seem to be following it properly.

I'm not sure what's happening.  Here's my full code:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP Lessons\Classes\getset.inc.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP Lessons\Classes\getset.inc.php on line 22

That line is:

```
getset::$name = 'Thomas';
```

Comment: Where are you assigning the value to `$name`?

Comment: Private property cannot be accessed outside of the Class, so it called private

Comment: @PraveenM Sorry, my getset line of code should be `getset::$name = 'Thomas';`  I've edited it.

Comment: AS @FerhadOthman mentioned, you can't access a private variable outside the class. You need a public method to set the value of `$name`.

Comment: `private $name;` -> `static $name;` ?

Comment: I used a scope resolution operator by accident.  I'll have to look up the difference between them and pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which may help you:

```
 <?php
      class getset {

        private $name;

        public function __set($property, $value) {
          if((property_exists($this, $property))) {
            $this->$property = $value;
            echo "Successfully updated {$property} to {$value}";
          } else {
             echo "This failed.";
          }
        }

      }
    $newObj=new getset();
    $newObj->name='Thomas';
    print_r($newObj);
?>
```

//Output:

```
    Successfully updated name to Thomas

    getset Object
    (
       [name:getset:private] => Thomas
    )
```

Comment: OK.  Thanks so much.  I used a scope resolution operator by accident.  I'll have to look up the difference between them and pointers.  Thanks so much!